# Is there a way to tell if a user is registered with phone number or email & password on Firebase Auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am building a React App with Firebase back end.
I have two types of users, Admin and Standard users. The admins are created by a Super Admin using email and password and their phone numbers is set to their profile. The Standard user registers using phone number. I would like to send a different registration success SMS for the Admin and the standard user using Firebase cloud functions with the onCreate auth trigger.

Is there a way to tell which user was created through Admin SDK and which one registered through phone Auth.

My create Admin function is as below.

```
exports.addAdmin= functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        displayName: data.name,
        phoneNumber: data.phone,
        disabled: false,
        emailVerified: true
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `email` and `phoneNumber` are defined in `user` object of `onCreate()` function like this:

```
export const onUserCreate = auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  if (user.phoneNumber) {
    // User has phone number
  }

  if (user.email) {
    // User has email
  }
});
```

If both admin created and standard users can have email-password auth setup and you want check if they were created by a super admin or no, then you'll have to store the source in a database or custom claims. Try:

```
export const addAdmin = https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const user = await getAuth().createUser({
    email: "dharmaraj.r244@gmail.com",
    password: "data.password",
  });

  // Add 'source' custom claim
  await getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
    source: "admin",
  });

  return 'User created';
});
```

```
export const onUserCreate = auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const { customClaims } = await getAuth().getUser(user.uid);

  if (customClaims.source === "admin") {
    console.log("User created by super admin")
  }

  return null;
});
```